# C# - Google Drive SDK - Storing client and secret ID in winform

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have written a C# winform program that uses the google drive SDK and that I want to release publicly. However, I'm not sure if it's safe to store my Google Drive client and secret ID's in the source code, and if it's not, what is the recommended way to store them?

Example, i have a class that explicitly defines two varialbes - String CLIENT_ID =  and String SECRET_ID = . If I send out the .exe for this, is this information easily attained by someone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using a tool like reflector, you can pull out that information in a few seconds.

The answer is, don't use YOUR google drive. Make the user use their drive. Or, if it's something your program needs to just READ...well, make the file public.